# ReactJS - sorting - TypeError: 0 is read only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I'm trying to sort an object before mapping it in reactjs, but every single time I do, I keep getting the TypeError: 0 is read only. I noticed that on load the props are empty, but even when I was trying to check the length of the array and only apply sort when it's higher than 0, or when the array exists to be precised, it would still happen. The moment I try to sort anything, it just stops working.

I would like to be able to sort these via different criteria in the future, but so far I can't even go through regular sorting on render...

I have the below:

**ToysList.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class ToysList extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
}


render () {
    var toys = this.props.toys;
    var arr = toys.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));

    return (
        <div>
            <div key="list">
               { arr.map((toy, index) => (
                    <div key={toy.id}>
                        {toy.name}:<br/>
                        Quantity: {toy.quantity}<br/>
                        Price: {toy.price}<br/>
                        Rating: {toy.rating}
                    </div>
                )) }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ToysList.propTypes = {
toys: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string,
        name: PropTypes.string,
        quantity:PropTypes.number,
        price:PropTypes.number,
        rating:PropTypes.number,
    }),
).isRequired,
};


export default ToysList;
```

I'd be grateful for any hint with these. 
Thanks

Comment: You dont get a warning telling you that map function should return something ?

Comment: What is the default value of toys? I had similar problems when I initialized an array with a wrong type. For example with an empty object literal instead of string literal.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That could be because `sort` mutates the array it works on (*it sorts in-place*).

If `this.props.toys` is immutable then it would throw that error.

Create a copy of the array and sort that.

```
var toys = this.props.toys.slice();
// var toys = Array.from(this.props.toys);
// var toys = [...this.props.toys];
var arr = toys.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));
```

**Update 2023**

ECMAScript 2023 introduced the [`.toSorted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted)  method of the array, which is the non-mutating version of `.sort`.

This way you can now skip the copying of the array before sorting it.

```
var toys = this.props.toys;
var arr = toys.toSorted((a,b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a clone of toys:

```
var toys = [...this.props.toys];
var arr = toys.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));
```