# Comparator in Typescript for custom sort on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

So I want to use a custom sort on an array I get that is always in a different order: `[{code: 'A'},{code: 'O'},{code: 'I'}],  [{code: 'O'},{code: 'A'},{code: 'I'}], ...`

I want it in the  `[{code: 'A'},{code: 'O'},{code: 'I'}]` order.

```
export function someSort(arrayToSort): Array {
  if (!arrayToSort || arrayToSort.length < 1) {
    return [];
  }
  const sorted = new Map();
  const sorting = ['A', 'O', 'I'];

  for (let i = 0; i < sorting.length; ++i) {
    sorted.set(sorting[i], i);
  }
  return arrayToSort.sort((a, b) => sorted.get(a.code) - sorted.get(b.code));
}
```

I tried this where I add the sorting I want to a map with key the 'A' and as value a number so it's sortable but I get an error `core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'` And now I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I allowed myself to change your tags to adapt them to your question (I get it that you use Angular, but the question isn't related to Angular because it doesn't involve any Angular feature). If you feel this is unfair, please let me know.

Comment: So is your issue that the array is frozen?  You might want to do `arrayToSort.slice().sort(...)` instead, so you're sorting a copy of the array and not the array itself.  Do note, it helps to provide a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  Good luck!

Comment: Is this the issue? [Error while sorting array of objects Cannot assign to read only property '2' of object '\[object Array\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53420326/3082296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array comes from the redux store and it's immutable so I solved it by doing `slice()` before I call `sort()`. But still [@Maryannah's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287061/3527103) is a lot better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You're reaching too far.

Using only an array to sort is enough, rely on the index of the items in it.

```js
const data = [
  { code: 'O' },
  { code: 'A' },
  { code: 'I' },
];

const order = ['A', 'O', 'I'];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.code) - order.indexOf(b.code));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: If OP got the error with their code, they should get an error with this as well

Comment: That's a lot more readable, wrote some unittests and both yours and mine work so the bug  is elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @adiga indeed, didn't focus at all on the error but on the code readability !

Comment: @BurstofIce okay, if you could please provide a [mcve] of your issue, we could better understand it ! Consider using https://stackblitz.com if you use Angular !

Comment: @BurstofIce But, if you have a lot of objects in your array, your code is better because this is `O(n2)`

Comment: @adiga well that's a bit more complicated when it comes to the complexity, since they aren't the same array and thus, not necessarily have the same number of items in it (but that's not the point of the question)

Comment: @BurstofIce please check if the array you are passing to this function is frozen

Comment: @Maryannah could you add slice() to your solution and I'll mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: @adiga yeah didn't know that it was possible in typescript to have immutable arrays

Comment: @BurstofIce Nah mate, I didn't resolve your issue, I do not deserve the points for it. I'm fine with just an upvote ! Instead, accept your own answer, or the one that put you on track, so that people with th same issue can see it first hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't throw a runtime error for me, but it throws a build error re: type declaration. An `Array` requires a type, even if it's `any`. Changing your function declaration to

```
export function someSort(arrayToSort): Array<any> {
```

fixed it for me (as in: builds, runs and produces expected result).