# Sorting array of objects according to the date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

```
[
0: {date: "02-04-2020", count: 1}
1: {date: "16-04-2020", count: 2}
2: {date: "10-04-2020", count: 1}
3: {date: "15-04-2020", count: 4}
4: {date: "04-04-2020", count: 4}
]
```

From the above array of objects I need to  sort them  according to date and get the output as follows

```
    [
    0: {date: "02-04-2020", count: 1}
    1: {date: "04-04-2020", count: 4}
    2: {date: "10-04-2020", count: 1}
    3: {date: "15-04-2020", count: 4}
    4: {date: "16-04-2020", count: 2}
    ]
```

I tried using the following method

```
const sorted_array = data
          .slice()
          .sort(
            (a, b) => new Date(a.date).valueOf() - new Date(b.date).valueOf()
          );
```

I used .slice before sort since I get the error  `Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]` so I referred [Error while sorting array of objects Cannot assign to read only property '2' of object '[object Array]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420055/error-while-sorting-array-of-objects-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-2-of/53420326) and added slice.

But the sorting is not done correctly, I need some help in fixing this. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have the keys in your array?

Comment: Is the property `date` or `_id`?

Comment: date, sry I just changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be encountering an issue with `new Date(...)` not handling strings of this format since it's not a standard format. `new Date("02-04-2020")` interprets it as February 4, 2020, and `new Date("16-04-2020")` produces an error. It's seeming to use American date formats here, where we backwardsly use month before day.

If your dates were in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, then `new Date(...)` would work properly, so if you're able to change that, that'll be the smoothest route. If you cannot change the format, you'll want to consider changing the sorting thusly:

```
const sorted_array = data
  .map(addSortableColumn)
  .sort(bySortColumn)
  .map(removeSortableColumn);

function addSortableColumn(item) {
  const [day, month, year] = item.date.split('-');
  return { ...item, _sortBy: year + month + day };
}

function bySortColumn(a, b) {
  return a._sortBy.localeCompare(b._sortBy);
}

function removeSortableColumn(item) {
  const { _sortBy, ...otherProps } = item;
  return otherProps;
}
```

(if you don't care about removing the sort column, you can skip that last step)

**Update**

If you need to preserve object prototypes, it was correctly pointed out that spread syntax destroys this. Another approach that I actually like even better is to store the sort columns in a separate map. The reason why it's even being stored is to avoid the sort keys needing to be computed multiple times.

```
const sortKeys = new Map();

const sorted_array = data.slice().sort(byDDMMYYYY);

function byDDMMYYYY(a, b) {
  return getSortKey(a).localeCompare(getSortKey(b));
}

function getSortKey(item) {
  let key = sortKeys.get(item);
  if (!key) {
    const [day, month, year] = item.date.split('-');
    key = year + month + day;
    sortKeys.set(item, key);
  }
  return key;
}
```

Comment: That was great, thank you so much for the explanation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to @Jacob's answer for an explanation of your mistake. Here's an alternative solution using regex to change your date to the correct format:

```
const pattern = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;
const repl = "$3-$2-$1";
const sorted_array = data
      .slice()
      .sort(
          (a, b) => new Date(a.date.replace(pattern, repl)) - 
                    new Date(b.date.replace(pattern, repl))
      );
```

Also note that you don't need to compare `valueOf()` from the `Date`s, arithmetic has been overloaded for `Date` already to allow native comparison of the objects.

Edit: changed `repl` to ISO 8601-compatible format of YYYY-MM-DD according to the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-date-time-string-format).

Comment: I'd suggest `repl = "$3-$2-$1";` instead, since that's an _officially_ supported format.

Comment: Is specifically ISO 8601

Comment: While `new Date(a.date.replace(pattern, repl))` works in this case, it's an incorrect parse as it treats the date as UTC. Creating a Date isn't necessary, comparing "$3-$2-$1" as strings is sufficient (and possibly more efficient). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is not correct. 
DD-MM-YYYY is not a valid date format.

```
new Date("15-04-2020")
```

will return **Invalid Date**

You need to convert your date to ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD [according to the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-date-time-string-format).

```js
const data = [ 
  {_id: "02-04-2020", count: 1},
  {_id: "16-04-2020", count: 2},
  {_id: "10-04-2020", count: 1},
  {_id: "15-04-2020", count: 4},
  {_id: "04-04-2020", count: 4},
];

console.log("Original Data: ", data);

// Something like that.
const dataSorted = data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
  const [dayA, monthA, yearA] = a._id.split("-");
  const [dayB, monthB, yearB] = b._id.split("-");
  return new Date(`${yearA}-${monthA}-${dayA}`) 
    - new Date(`${yearB}-${monthB}-${dayB}`)
});

console.log("Data sorted by date: ", dataSorted);
```